# Hibernate долго выполняет запрос

Tags: hibernate, java, firebird

Запрос:

```
SELECT GEN_ID('GEN12', 1) FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

В базе выполняется 0 ms, через hibernate 30-90 ms.

Код:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.createSQLQuery(sql).uniqueResult();
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": time exec")
session.close();
```

Как можно ускорить?

UPD:
Измерение было не одно.
измерение было также такого вида:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   session.createSQLQuery(sql).uniqueResult();
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + ": time exec")
session.close();
```

где count 50, 100, 1000, 5000. В среднем время запроса 50-60 ms

Comment: Если было одно измерение, то не очень показательный метод определения времени исполнения.

Comment: Это просто догадка (скорее неправильная). Может быть это связано с Serializable. Т.е. возможно, что Hibernate "заточен" для serialized объектов.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Что на выходе всегда должен быть Serializable? так session.createSQLQuery(sql).uniqueResult(); так на выходе String, а он Serializable. 

Или вы имели ввиду что hibernate никогда не сможет быстро выполнить запрос?

Comment: Да, здесь это ничего не объясняет. Погорячился с предположениями.

Answer (score 3):

А это, на сколько я знаю, сессия долго открывается. Запрос же проходит очень быстро. В `Hibernate` очень много всякой тягомотины, которая довольно долго инициализируется. У меня тож такая проблема была (с очень длительными операциями). Я ее исправил тем, что создал один класс-*синглтон*, который за весь период работы приложения один раз подключается к базе данных и инициализируется. Результат - приложение стало работать в раз 15 быстрее. Т.е. я избавился от длительной инициализации сессии для произведения транзакций с базой.

PS. Если вы попробуете то же самое сделать при помощи `JDBC` то, уверен, операция пройдет намного быстрее.

Comment: Нужно уточнить, это первая сессия долго открывается - она получается новое соединение с БД, инициализирует еще всякое добро. Если вы выполните такой же код (с созданием `Session` и проч.) еще раз сразу после вашего, то он выполнится гораздо быстрее. @Антон Мухин, вы ведь говорите про единовременную иниализацию `SessionFactory`? На всякий случай: `Session` не является потокобезопасным и его создание недорого обходится (кроме тех случаев, когда создается новое соединение) и разработчики Hibernate рекомнедуют создавать новую сессию для каждого логического юнита работы.

Comment: 1. @Антон Мухин посмотрите на код. Открытие и закрытие сессии идет вне замера времени. 
 2. Конечно можно переписать на jdbc, но неужели нельзя через Hibernate быстро выполнить запрос? 
 3. Это далеко не первая сессия, первые запросы идут дольше, (100 - 120 ms) их в расмотр не беру.

Comment: И наверняка ещё имеет смысла позаботить о connection pool, чтобы ещё и соединение каждый раз не устанавливать.

Answer (score 2):

Возможная причина, если до указанного native запроса есть загрузка объектов через `Session.get()`.

Hibernate проверяет уже загруженные сущности на изменения в БД. Ваш нативный запрос мог изменить данные в базе и Hbernate должен удостовериться, что сущности в сессии находятся в актуальном состоянии - другими слова, происходит "flush", по терминологии Hibernate/JPA. Это можно отключить, установив у сессии `FlushMode.MANUAL` (вам придется синхронизировать состоянии сессии самостоятельно, если это необходимо) или `FlushMode.COMMIT` (синхронизация по коммиту транзакции). Только будьте осторожны, если в вашем запросе таки происходят изменения, которые должны затронуть загруженные сущности. Другой вариант - перенести native запрос в метод с отдельной сессией.

Comment: > Другой вариант - перенести native запрос в метод с отдельной сессией.

То есть сделать как у меня в коде, открывается сессия, выполнятся запрос, и закрывается сессия? К сожалению не работает. 
А сделать flush можно попробовать, спасибо.